# How to inspect files compiled by webpack before they are emitted

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

I'm using webpack (v4) to package assets for my UI application.  I'd like to run a function that checks the contents of the compiled assets for invalid strings ideally *before* the files are emitted to the output directory.  In coming up with an initial approach, I happily stumbled upon webpack hooks which seems to be exactly what I need to accomplish my task.

Unfortunately, the documentation is a little lacking or at least I'm still left with some uncertainty after reviewing it. My first challenge is determining which hook to use.  It seems like I need a Compiler hook (rather than Compilation hook) and the [emit hook](https://v4.webpack.js.org/api/compiler-hooks/#emit) seems to be the one I'm interested in. Going with that, here is what I have so far:

```
plugins: [
  {
    apply(compiler: webpack.Compiler) {
      compiler.hooks.emit.tap('ValidateEmittedAssetsPlugin', (compilation) => {
        const { assets } = compilation;

        Object.entries(assets).forEach(([pathname, source]) => {
          const contents = (source as Buffer).buffer.toString();
          if (contents.indexOf(SOME_INVALID_STRING) > -1) {
            console.log('File contained invalid string. Failing build.');
            return false;
          }

          // Trying to toString() source.buffer hasn't worked so I've also tried 
          // the following also to no avail.
          //
          // const file = compilation.getAsset(pathname);
          // const contents = file.source.buffer.toString();
          }
        });
        return true;
      });
    },
  },
]
```

I am able to successfully iterate through the files to be emitted, but I am unable to get the contents of those assets. Since they are (I'm guessing) in-memory, I can't use something like `fs` to read the files from the file system. I also attempted to use `compilation.getAsset()` (as noted above) to no avail.  So my challenge is getting the contents of the in-memory assets in the `emit` hook.

**How can I use webpack hooks to check the contents of a compiled asset before it is emitted?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want control the emitting assets you must use **`compiler.hooks.shouldEmit`** hook, with it's return value you can actually control. Which you cant control with **`compiler.hooks.emit`** hook. Both execute before emitting assets but **`shouldEmit`** allow to control emitting assets.

Once you get entries from **`compilation.asset`**, you can call **`compilation.getAsset(<asset_name>)`** to get asset and **`asset.source.source()`** returns you the content.

You can use either **`emit`** or **`shouldEmit`** hook depending on your preference.

I prefer having separate js file to manage output, rather plugin logic into  `module.plugin` array. You can also pass configuration into constructor to have more control over output.

AssetValidatorPlugin.js

```
const PLUGIN_NAME = 'AssetValidatorPlugin';

class AssetValidatorPlugin {

    constructor(options){
        this.options = options;
    }

    apply(compiler) {
        // to check content of emitted assets
        compiler.hooks.emit.tap(PLUGIN_NAME, (compilation) => {
            let assets = Object.entries(compilation.assets);
            assets.forEach(([fileName]) => {
                const asset = compilation.getAsset(fileName);
                const assetContent = asset.source.source();
                console.log(assetContent);
            })
        });

        // to check content of emitted assets and prevent when fail to pass checks
        compiler.hooks.shouldEmit.tap(PLUGIN_NAME, (compilation) => {
            let allCheckPassed = true;
            let assets = Object.entries(compilation.assets);
            const logger = compiler.getInfrastructureLogger(PLUGIN_NAME);

            logger.info('Asset check');

            for (let fileIndex = 0; fileIndex < assets.length; fileIndex++) {
                const [fileName] = assets[fileIndex];

                logger.info(`validating ${fileName}`)
                const asset = compilation.getAsset(fileName);
                const assetContent = asset.source.source();

                if (assetContent.indexOf('some inane string') > -1) {
                    logger.error(`invalid string found in ${fileName} `);
                    allCheckPassed = false;
                    break;
                }
            };

            logger.info('Asset check completed');
            if (allCheckPassed)
                logger.info('asset emit proceeded');
            else
                logger.warn('asset emit aborted');
            
            if(this.options.stopEmitOnError)
                return allCheckPassed;

            return true;
        });
    }
}

module.exports = AssetValidatorPlugin;
```

and add it to webpack.config.js

```
const AssetValidatorPlugin = require('./AssetValidatorPlugin');

module.exports= {
    entry: {...},
    module:{...},
    plugins: [
        new AssetValidatorPlugin({stopEmitOnError: true}),
        ...
    ]
};
```

**Both hooks works the same on Webpack v4/v5. Also you can get the asset content in same manner.**

Comment: Thanks! I'll go with `shouldEmit` since that seems like the easier way to error a compilation. `asset.source.source()` was the main thing I got from your code, although `compiler.getInfrastructureLogger(PLUGIN_NAME)` is a big help too.